# In Ansible, how do I iterate over stdout that has an array?

Tags: ansible-2.x

Ansible v2.6.3

I have an task that gets all the container ARNs in my AWS ECS cluster like this

```
- name: List jenkins cluster container instances
  command: "aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster jenkins"
  register: jenkins_containers

- debug: var=jenkins_containers.stdout
```

and the output is this (the arn part is modified)

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "jenkins_containers.stdout": {
        "containerInstanceArns": [
            "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn0", 
            "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn1", 
            "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn2"
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I iterate over the containerInstanceArns field so I can for example

```
- debug: msg="Container ARN is {{ item }}"
  with_items: jenkins_containers.stdout.containerInstanceArns
```

or

```
- debug: msg="Container ARN is {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ jenkins_containers.stdout.containerInstanceArns }}"
```

Neither of above code works of course.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had to do this

```
- name: List jenkins cluster container instances
  command: "aws ecs list-container-instances --cluster jenkins"
  register: jenkins_containers

- set_fact:
    containers: "{{ jenkins_containers.stdout }}"

- debug: msg="{{ item }}" 
  with_items: "{{ containers.containerInstanceArns }}"
```

Isn't there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `with_subelements`. From: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements

> Subelements walks a list of hashes (aka dictionaries) and then traverses a list with a given (nested sub-)key inside of those records.

```
---

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
  - myvar: {'stdout': {'containerInstanceArns': ['arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn0', 'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn1', 'arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn2']}}

  tasks:
  - debug: 
      msg: '{{ item[1] }}'
    with_subelements:
    - '{{ myvar }}'
    - 'containerInstanceArns'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Why the index 1 in item[1]? Is that b/c "containerArns" is item 1 in with_subelements?

Comment: I just tried this and get "TASK [jenkins-slave : debug] ***************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {}

MSG:

subelements lookup expects a dictionary, got '[]' "

Comment: @ChrisF the `with_subelements` should be i.e.: `{{ jenkins_container }}` and not `{{ jenkins_container.stdout }}`. The items return values are i.e.: `[{}, "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:arn0"]`, the `item[1]` is to access the item at index 1 in the list. The empty `{}` in this case is due to having no other dicts in the `stdout`.